# How to set up samba

Tags: linux, windows, networking, samba

Hi I'm a long time linux user with some modest skill but I've always really used one where most of the stuff is already set up.
Now I'm starting out on my own and just gotten a little stuck with samba.
Normally you set the share and away you go - but I need to set up the configuration and I'm a little stuck.
Our network (windows based) has no workgroup and uses a domain instead - how do I use that in the windows networking options? To achieve what I want? Which is to be able to see the folder in my network list on my windows machine and then save, edit files etc.

I've got the basics of the box going and have webmin installed and working so just this would really be helpful.

Sorry if I'm a little vague this is really the first time I've set the up.

Thanks for your help.
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the chapter from samba guide for configuring samba with domains http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html#domain-member-server

Have you gone through it? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, have to say that document might as well be in french, but trying my best! I'm not too sure where to find half that information. At present I can type in the config (what I think is correct) but then it can't find a suitable server for the domain that I've entered. Maybe you could help me - find the information on my windows machine and then enter it correctly.
Thanks in advance.
Richard

Comment: The server that you need is the domain controller. Most likely this will be running Windows Server Edition. You need the hostname of that machine.